# Heroku still referencing old database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I've provisioned and switched to a new database in my heroku app. And it seemed to work fine, but now I attempted to run the console and it had the data from my old database. I ran `heroku addons:destroy <DATABASE_URL> --remote live` and now the hobby-dev db has been destroyed and now when I try to run a query from the console I get `PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "fgedboaquoao" is not permitted to log in`

Anybody know how I can stop my app from referencing the old database?

Comment: Have you checked your environment variables? The `DATABASE_URL` should be pointing to your new database. You can run `heroku config` to check your env vars.

Comment: I had it hard coded in my `production.rb` to share the databases. that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had it hard coded in my `production.rb` to share the databases. that was the problem